# Modulus numeric syntax fails in the cloud

Tags: bash

I have tried one of the implementations for maximum threads from the internet. I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$BASH_VERSION"
echo "$-"
processes=4
i=0
((i=i%$processes)); ((i++==0)) && wait
```

This failed without any error messages on DNANexus platform on aws. On the other hand, when I rewrote it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$BASH_VERSION"
echo "$-"
processes=4
i=0
(( ++i % $processes == 0 )) && wait
```

The code works. The bash version is 4.3.11(1)-release, the shell flags are ehB

Can anyone try to guess why this happens on the cloud, while locally in OsX and Ubuntu 18.04 both versions work fine?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your minimal and complete comment. I added the definition of processes, which reproduces the error.

Comment: Please add `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` output from both working and failing shell instances.

Comment: Also, output from `echo "$-"` may be relevant; if the `u` flag is set, that would make references to undefined variables cause an abort. (If setting `i=0` on the site where the failure otherwise occurs makes it go away, that argues in favor of the above explanation as well).

Comment: Thank you, those comments are actually helpful for debugging. I have found the Bash version, I will add the other line and update accordingly.

Comment: Edited the Q. Just to add that on my local machine where it works, the flags are himBHs.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), exercise #2. Though I thought behavior changed somewhere in the 4.x series, the matter of it being so variable (version- and runtime-configuration-dependent) is much of why `set -e` usage is ill-advised.

Comment: (BTW, it's interesting that `set -e` is being set, when your shebang doesn't specify it and you don't have a line in your script enabling it. It's *possible* to enable such flags through the environment, but that's unusual and not something I see often; if you don't offhand know why/how the flag is set, that's a thing that can be investigated).

Comment: Hmm. `#!/bin/bash` on MacOS should result in a `$BASH_VERSION` of 3.2.x; to get 4.x there when the shebang is being honored, you typically need `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and a more modern version of bash in the PATH, as installed by Nix/MacPorts/Homebrew/etc.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't test on OsX, I only wrote the result for Linux 18.04 as that was more  relevant. I only mentioned OsX in the first iteration to try and ease up. That is where the confusion stems from.

This is executed on DNANExus platform which obviously has a wrapper around my script, so that might explain the unusual behavior of set -e?

Comment: Right, it sounds like their wrapper is forcing the flag. That's unfortunately common; even though `set -e` makes scripts behave a lot less predictably, a lot of folks pushed it early on as bash's equivalent to perl "strict mode", and often do still encourage its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is operation of `set -e`, the flag otherwise known as `errexit`.

In the case of:

```
((i=i%$processes)); ((i++==0)) && wait
```

...the command `(( i++ == 0 ))` is treated as a conditional, and so the behavior of aborting on nonzero exit status typically caused by `errexit` is avoided *only* for `(( i++ == 0 ))`, and not for `(( i=i%$processes ))`, on version of bash which don't have an explicit exception for arithmetic expressions from being subject to `set -e` behavior.

---

See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), exercise #2.